# PHP is it unwise to redefine/reuse a variable

Tags: php, variables

Is it risky in any way or considered bad practice to "modify" a variable a single time like this? I know not to create confusion and conflict by re-using `$A` for any other functions, but within a single simple function like this? Seems like defining new variables just for output strings with the units like this is wasteful and in a long program would really add up.

```
if (whatever conditions) {
    $A = $X * $Y;
    if (user selected ft as units) {
        $A = $A / 304.8.' ft';
    }
    elseif (user selected in as units) {
        $A = $A / 25.4.' in';
    }
    echo $A
}
```

Comment: That looks perfectly fine to me, assuming that the user selected something, and it's one of the two choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's generally alternative ways to this which also don't require defining new variables, like e.g. move this to a function which `return`s the value which you then store in a variable once (which will also declutter code).

Example:

```
function getA($X,$Y) {
    if (user selected ft as units) {
        return ($X * $Y) / 304.8.' ft';
    }
    elseif (user selected in as units) {
        return ($X * $Y) / 25.4.' in';
    }      
}

if (whatever conditions) {
   echo getA($X,$Y);
}
```

Or in your specific case have two echos, one in each if e.g.

```
if (whatever conditions) {
    $A = $X * $Y;
    if (user selected ft as units) {
        echo ($A / 304.8).' ft';
    }
    elseif (user selected in as units) {
        echo ($A / 25.4).' in';
    }
}
```

Re-defining `$A` the way you are doing is bad practice because it makes it unclear as to what the purpose of `$A` is. Is it the result of a mathematical operation or is it a presentational element?

If you must re-use it at least re-use it for the same purpose.

Answer (score 3):

*Short answer:*

**no**

*Long answer:*

This depends on the context and how large your function body is, and/or how complex is the code around the snippet.

The alternatives in coding that flow would be:

- using an else, and duplicating code (moving the multiplication in each if block), and this of course would not be good
- using other weird-ish constructs like `switch(true)`

The snippet of code you wrote looks quite alright to me, and i would consider the `if` statements as **updating** the `$A` variable rather than **reusing** it. I personally use it often, and so do my colleagues.

Again, visibility depends on the surrounding code. If this snippet would be inside another `if`, that would not be good, but not because the variable updating, but because you're stacking too many `if`s.